# IntelliJ Idea Filter Implementation by Scope

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, scope, keyboard-shortcuts

Using IntelliJ Idea Community 2016.2.3 on my Mac, I am able to filter the show usages (⌘B)  dialog by production files, however, unable to do the same thing for implementation(s) (⌥⌘B).

For the dialog that appears for the implementations, there is no symbol to set the settings to for scopes.

I have tried using defining my own scope, however, that is only an option for find dialogs and is not available for the implementations dialog.

Comment: You might have more luck asking in the [JetBrains support community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users)